# Examples of Topological sorts in Massive graphs

Tags: bioinformatics, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I am interested in finding some real world massive data sets (>=1M) which needed to be topologically sorted. Perhaps something relating to bioinformatics?

Comment: Is this a history question ("What big data sets has someone sorted topologically?") or a request for examples ("What accessible data sets might be interesting to sort topologically?")?

Comment: @DavisHerring The later. I am in need of some "big data" applications of topological sorting.

Comment: The "Related" list suggests [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260847/examples-for-topological-sorting-on-large-dags).

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/)? There are plenty of real world datasets, huge ones too, many of them directed.

Comment: I did, but I don't see why you would need to topologically sort them. I did try to think of a "meaning" of their sort but it just made slight to no sense

Answer (score 1):

There are [650k commits](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2017/the-biggest-and-weirdest-commits-in-linux-kernel-git-history) in the Linux git history; performing a topological sort on the separate commits would have the plausible purpose of rediscovering the branches (merged or no).

You could extend this well past a million objects by including the other Git object types (tags, trees, and blobs): then the topological sort would reconstruct the directory hierarchies as well as the commit history.